# Take the intersection of an arbitrary number of lists in python

Tags: python, algorithm, list, intersection

Suppose I have a list of lists of elements which are all the same (i'll use `int`s in this example)

```
[range(100)[::4], range(100)[::3], range(100)[::2], range(100)[::1]]
```

What would be a nice and/or efficient way to take the intersection of these lists (so you would get every element that is in each of the lists)?
For the example that would be:

```
[0, 12, 24, 36, 48, 60, 72, 84, 96]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use sets, which have an intersection method.

```
>>> s = set()
>>> s.add(4)
>>> s.add(5)
>>> s
set([4, 5])
>>> t = set([2, 4, 9])
>>> s.intersection(t)
set([4])
```

For your example, something like

```
>>> data = [range(100)[::4], range(100)[::3], range(100)[::2], range(100)[::1]]
>>> sets = map(set, data)
>>> print set.intersection(*sets)
set([0, 96, 36, 72, 12, 48, 84, 24, 60])
```

Comment: I'll put this as the best answer, because it's a little faster than my own (which is in turn twice as fast as the ones using reduce) and because the neat thing with the multiple sets at once. Thanks!

Comment: Alternatively, `set.intersection(set(x) for x in data)`

Comment: @thepandaatemyface, I'm always glad to hear my code performs well, but always a bit suspicious as well. I'm sure it depends on the input a lot and you don't have time to have ran it on truly huge input if size of input was the issue. If I was trying to optimize for speed in an inner loop on large data, I would consider trying `set(datas[0]).intersection(*datas[1:])` out and timing it, which has a nice ring of performance to me.

Comment: @Mike Graham, what I meant to say is: of all the elegant solutions posted here, yours was the fastest. I quickly tested it with a [[randint(0, 100000) for i in range(1000)] for i in range(100)] as my data. It's not very scientific, but it seems to keep giving yours as the fastest.

Comment: @David, you're missing a `*(...)` to apply the generator's items as args. Other than that, that's certainly a fine approach. The main reason I didn't use it was to emphasize that if you're doing operations like intersection, you should probably *already* have sets.

Comment: @thepandaatemyface, Awesome. =)

Answer (score 4):

I think the built-in `set` module should do the trick.

```
>>> elements = [range(100)[::4], range(100)[::3], range(100)[::2], range(100)[::1]]
>>> sets = map(set, elements)
>>> result = list(reduce(lambda x, y: x & y, sets))
>>> print result
[0, 96, 36, 72, 12, 48, 84, 24, 60]
```

Comment: You beat me to the punch. I'll leave my answer up as it applies `reduce` slightly differently, but I'm glad to see that other people think functionally too. :-)

Comment: Too many schools skip the (imho mandatory) introductory functional programming course by skipping straight to Java. Come on guys, SCIP is about the best introductory CS book ever...

Comment: Note that `set` is a type, not a module. (The set type used to be in a module called `sets`, but it is long deprecated.)

Comment: although it's very elegant and works just fine, this seems to be twice as slow as the solutions not using reduce. Anyone have any ideas why?

Comment: It could be due to having to build more intermediary sets.

Answer (score 3):

Convert them to sets and use the `set.intersection` method, reducing over the list of sets:

```
xs = [range(100)[::4], range(100)[::3], range(100)[::2], range(100)[::1]]
reduce(set.intersection, [set(x) for x in xs])
```

`reduce` is a functional programming device that iterates through any iterable and applies the function provided to the first two elements, then to the result and the next, and then the result of *that* and the next, and so on.

Comment: `set.intersection` takes an arbitrary number of iterables as arguments (in recent Pythons). If I'm not mistaken, this can be implemented with better algorithmic complexity than the `reduce` method provides.

Comment: @Mike: That's brilliant. I had no idea.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to answer my own question:

```
lists =  [range(100)[::4],range(100)[::3],range(100)[::2],range(100)[::1]]

out = set(lists[0])
for l in lists[1:]:
    out = set(l).intersection(out)

print out
```

or

```
print list(out)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a one-liner using the good old `all()` built-in function:

```
list(num for num in data[0] 
     if all(num in range_ for range_ in data[1:]))
```

Interestingly, this is (I think) more readable *and* faster than using `set` for larger data sets.

Answer (score 0):

You can treat them as sets and use `set.intersection()`:

```
lists = [range(100)[::4], range(100)[::3], range(100)[::2], range(100)[::1]]
sets = [set(l) for l in lists]

isect = reduce(lambda x,y: x.intersection(y), sets)
```

Comment: This would raise `AttributeError`?

Comment: Oops, `intersect` -> `intersection` (fixed).

Answer (score 0):

```
l = [range(100)[::4], range(100)[::3], range(100)[::2], range(100)[::1]]
l = [set(i) for i in l]
intersect = l[0].intersection(l[1])
for i in l[2:]:
    intersect = intersect.intersection(i)
```

Comment: This would raise `NameError` ?

Comment: I don't think so, @MikeGraham. Perhaps you are referring to the code that was here before I edited. I ran the old code and got an error, but this code has been tested and woks fine

Comment: @inspectG4dget, I was referring to the code before it was edited (my comment appears at least as old as the edit?) This code will not exibit that error, though I must confess I find your design a bit odd.

Comment: @MikeGraham: I saw the timing of the edit and the comment, which is why I suggested that your comment may have been posted before the edit. But I am curious as to why and how you would change the design of this.

Comment: @MikeGraham: Very true. I had thought of doing this, but I wanted to be more transparent with my code - especially since I did not document it at all. I don't know how proficient @thepandaatemyface is and therefore wanted to keep this as simple as possible.

Comment: I don't see how my first example is any more complex than your code, but I suppose that's what makes the world go 'round. `:)`